# .bashrc file preventing some SFTP GUI APP from logging to the VM

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sftp

I have a .bashrc file running on my Ubuntu server

```
red="\[\033[0;31m\]"
white="\[\033[1;37m\]"

toilet --gay -f mini  " RSM PRODUCTION ";
export PS1="$white┌──[$red\u$white@$red\h$white]──$white[$red\w$white] \n└── $white"

#================================
#            Alias              =
#================================

alias L='ls -a -lrt'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias install='sudo apt-get install'
alias update='sudo apt-get update'
alias upgrade='sudo apt-get -u upgrade'
alias agi='sudo apt-get install'
alias agu='sudo apt-get update'
alias agg='sudo apt-get -u upgrade'

# personal aliases
alias ls='ls -hF --color'    # add colors for filetype recognition
alias lx='ls -lXB'        # sort by extension
alias lk='ls -lSr'        # sort by size
alias la='ls -Al'        # show hidden files
alias lr='ls -lR'        # recursice ls
alias lt='ls -ltr'        # sort by date
alias lm='ls -al |more'        # pipe through 'more'
alias ll='ls -l'        # long listing
alias lsize='ls --sort=size -lhr' # list by size
alias lsd='ls -l | grep "^d"'   #list only directories
alias lalf='ls -alF'
alias acyl='cd ~/.icons/ACYL_Icon_Theme_0.9.3/ && bash AnyColorYouLike'
alias reboot='sudo shutdown -r now'
alias shutdown='sudo shutdown -h now'

#Command substitution
alias h='history | grep $1'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -v -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias which='type -all'
alias ..='cd ..'

#Bookmark Directory
alias dir_='cd /home/forge/rsm'

alias nginx_='cd /etc/nginx'
alias .ssh_='cd /root/.ssh'
alias ssh_='cd /etc/ssh'
alias root_='cd /root'
alias site_='cd /etc/nginx/sites-available'
alias bin_='cd /usr/local/bin'

dir_;
```

I can log-in to my VM perfectly fine via SSH.

I am not sure why in some SFTP client (GUI Apps) like `Cyberduck` preventing me from log-in into my VM. But when **remove** my .bashrc or deactivating it, it works fine.

---

## Questions

Is there a main reason behind this ?

What exactly is in my .bashrc that I shouldn't do ?

Comment: Try only remove the `toilet` line. It may confuse cyberduck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bashrc` file probably outputs stuff to stdout, which some SFTP programs might try to interpret as SFTP commands, leading to connection or authentication failure.

You should make sure your `bashrc` file only works for interactive sessions using one of [those two techniques](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html):

- Either testing the value of `PS1` (before your assignment of course) it will not be set for non-interactive sessions, or
- testing if `$-` contains `i` ; which will only happen for interactive sessions.

So your script would look like:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
red="\[\033[0;31m\]"
white="\[\033[1;37m\]"

toilet --gay -f mini  " RSM PRODUCTION ";
export PS1="$white┌──[$red\u$white@$red\h$white]──$white[$red\w$white] \n└── $white"
[...]
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug this would be add each line ( or chunks of lines ) to an empty .bashrc and attempt to login each time.  Eventually you'll add in a chunk of lines and not be able to log in, the offending command(s) are in that chunk.

My immediate hunch is the `toilet` command is messing with your gui tools in some way.